# ¿Como Comparar Arraylist en java?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

El ejercicio es el siguiente:
Queremos guardar los nombres y edades de los alumnos de un curso.
Realiza un programa que introduzca el nombre y la edad de cada uno.
El proceso de lectura de datos terminara cuando se introduzca como nombre un asterisco(*)
Al finalizar se mostraran los siguientes datos:

```
    1-> Todos los alumnos mayores de edad
    2-> Los alumnos mayores (Los que tienen mas edad)
```

Mi problema viene al realizar la condicion 2, alguno tiene ideas de como realizarla?
Aqui les planteo el codigo:

```
        ArrayList nombre = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList edad = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList mayorEdad = new ArrayList();

        String nm = "*";
        int nE = 0;
        String nombre_M;

        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; j != 0; i++) {

            System.out.println("Escriba el nombre del estudiante: ");
            nombre.add(sc_S.nextLine());
            nombre_M = (String) nombre.get(i);

            if (!(nombre.get(i)).equals(nm)) {
                System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del estudiante: ");
                edad.add(sc_I.nextInt());
                
                nE = (int) edad.get(i);

                if (nE > 17) {
                    mayorEdad.add(nombre_M);
                }
            }

            if ((nombre.get(i)).equals(nm)) {
                j = 0;
            }

        }
        
        System.out.println("Los Alumnos mayores de edad son: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < mayorEdad.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mayorEdad.get(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo una de las posibles implementaciones...

```
void comparaAlumnos() {
   Scanner sc_I = new Scanner( System.in );
   ArrayList<String> nombre = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<Integer> edad = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> mayorEdad = new ArrayList<>();
   String nm = "*";
   int nE = 0;
   String nombre_M;
      // eliminada la variable "j", para simplificar el código
      // int j = 1;
      // cambiamos la condición, para que sea un bucle infinito
   for( int i = 0; true; i++ ) {
      System.out.println( "Escriba el nombre del estudiante: " );
         // modificado en aras de la simplificación          
      nombre_M = sc_I.nextLine();
      if( nombre_M.equals( nm ) ) {
         break;
      }
      nombre.add( nombre_M );
      System.out.println( "Ingrese la edad del estudiante: " );    
      nE = sc_I.nextInt();
      edad.add( nE );

         // limpiamos el buffer para volver a leer cadenas
      sc_I.nextLine();
      if( nE > 17 ) {
         mayorEdad.add( nombre_M );
      }
   }
   System.out.println( "Los Alumnos mayores de edad son: " );
   for( int i = 0; i < mayorEdad.size(); i++ ) {
      System.out.println( mayorEdad.get( i ) );
   }

      // llamamos al método "ordenarEnParalelo", para después imprimir la mitad superior
   ordenarEnParalelo( edad, nombre );
   System.out.println( "Los Alumnos mayores son: " );

      // como la lista está ordenada, inicializamos "i", con un valor igual a "size() / 2"
   for( int i = nombre.size() / 2; i < nombre.size(); i++ ) {
      System.out.println( nombre.get( i ) + " que tiene " + edad.get( i ) + " años" );
   }
}

void ordenarEnParalelo( ArrayList<Integer> edad, ArrayList<String> nombre ) {

      // aplicamos el algoritmo de la burbuja, pero se puede reemplazar por cualquiera    
      // esta es la primer optimización del algoritmo, si la lista está ordena, termina su ejecución  
   boolean desordenado = true;
   while( desordenado ) {
      desordenado = false;
      int limite = edad.size() -1;
      for( int i = 0; i <  limite; i++ ) {
         int auxInt = edad.get( i );

            // si la edad de la posición es mayor que la de la siguiente, intercambiamos 
            // las posiciones, usando una variable auxiliar
         if( auxInt > edad.get( i + 1 ) ) {
            String AuxNom = nombre.get( i );
            nombre.set( i, nombre.get( i + 1 ) );
            nombre.set( i + 1, AuxNom );
            edad.set( i, edad.get( i + 1 ) );
            edad.set( i + 1, auxInt );
            desordenado = true;
         }

            // segunda optimización, en cada iteración, acortamos la cantidad de posiciones 
            // verificadas, dado que la última, siempre estará correctamente ubicada
         limite -= 1; 
      }
   }
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Un placer maestro!.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que podria ser lo que pides, yo lo he hecho con Objetos ya que es mucho más facil a la hora de comparar, no sé si es esto bien bien lo que pides...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombreAlumno = "";
    ArrayList<Alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Alumno> alumnosMasMayores = new ArrayList<>();

    while (!nombreAlumno.equals("*")) {
        System.out.print("Escriba el nombre del alumno: ");
        nombreAlumno = sc.nextLine();
        if (!nombreAlumno.equals("*")) {
            System.out.print("Escriba la edad del alumno: ");
            int edad = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            Alumno alumno = new Alumno(nombreAlumno, edad);
            alumnos.add(alumno);
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Proceso de lectura terminado");

    System.out.println("====== 1. Todos los alumnos mayores de edad ======");
    for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.size(); i++) {
        if (alumnos.get(i).edad >= 18) {
            alumnosMasMayores.add(alumnos.get(i));
            alumnos.get(i).datosAlumno();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("====== 2. Los alumnos mayores (Los que tienen mas edad)");
       Collections.sort(alumnosMasMayores, new Comparator<Alumno>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Alumno alumno1, Alumno alumno2) {
            return Integer.compare(alumno2.getEdad(), alumno1.getEdad());
        }
    });

    
    for (Alumno alumno : alumnosMasMayores) {
        alumno.datosAlumno();
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!